# From Tirole Book: If a single strategy profile survives iterated deletion of strictly dominated strategies, then it is a Nash equilibrium of the game.

Tags: proof-writing, self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

While I am reading [Tirole Game Theory Book](https://books.google.com.tr/books/about/Game_Theory.html?id=pFPHKwXro3QC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y) , I read the following statement

> If a single strategy profile survives iterated deletion of strictly dominated strategies, then it is a Nash equilibrium of the game.

How can I prove this statement?

I fact, I know that the converse is not true. That is, any Nash-equilibrium profile must put weight only on strategies that are not strictly dominated (or more generally, do not survive iterated deletion of strictly dominated strategies), because a player could increase his payoff by replacing a dominated strategy with one that dominates it. [However, Nash equilibria may assign positive probability to weakly dominated strategies]

But I cannot proceed anything for the other side of the statement.

I will be appreciated for all helps. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit it. @AnotherUser